# MYSQL URL for databases python

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi

I have a fastAPI project i have to connect to the database using databases library its a `mysql` db ut i cant reconstruct the url for databases, is there an alternative to using a url? or could someone fix the url?

```py
from databases import Database
# Database configuration
db_config = {
    "host": os.environ.get("DATABASE_HOSTNAME"),
    "user": os.environ.get("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
    "password": os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
    "database": os.environ.get("DATABASE_DBNAME"),
    "port": int(os.environ.get("DATABASE_PORT")),
}

# Database URL
database_url = f"mysql+aiomysql://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['password']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['database']}"

# Connect to the database
db = Database(database_url)


async def connect():
    await db.connect()


async def disconnect():
    await db.disconnect()
```

produces error:

```py
# .venv/bin/python3.10 -m uvicorn main:app --reload --port=8001 --host 0.0.0.0
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [126875] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [126877]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 734, in lifespan
    async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 610, in __aenter__
    await self._router.startup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 711, in startup
    await handler()
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/main.py", line 69, in startup
    await db.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/db.py", line 27, in connect
    await db.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 112, in connect
    await self._backend.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/databases/backends/mysql.py", line 71, in connect
    port=self._database_url.port or 3306,
  File "/home/ubuntu/***-web/BH_API/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 546, in port
    return self.components.port
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 185, in port
    raise ValueError(f"Port could not be cast to integer value as {port!r}")
ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'PASSWORD'

ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
```

if its of any help, i call the connect function from main.py

```py
# Connect to the DB on app startup
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await db.connect()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await db.disconnect()
```

any help is appreatiated

Comment: Does the password contain anything like `@`, `:` or `/`?

Comment: "Port could not be cast to integer value as 'PASSWORD'" are all of your .env variables set correctly and being used in the correct places?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes password does contain special chars specifically `=,&!#` alongside other chars and nums, does that change anything?

Comment: @chrisbyte yes iam sure all values are paired correctly.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks, you are on the right track, i need to encode the password in the url, you can add it as an answer for future visitors.
`from urllib.parse import quote; encoded_password = quote(password, safe='')`

Comment: Marked as duplicate of the SQLAlchemy question as databases uses SQLAlchemy under the hood.